# Toggle div if no items in list (notifications)

Tags: jquery

In my notifications code I am trying to implement an empty state div to show when all of the notifications have been deleted using the `.remove__icon`.

The problem is that the code below doesn't know when the `.activity__list` is empty. How do I set up a detection to know when all of the `.activity__item` have been removed from the `.activity__list` so that I can show / hide the `.activity--empty` div using the variables I set up?

```
  var hideEmpty = function() {
    $(".activity--empty").hide();
    $(".mark").hide();
  };
  var showEmpty = function() {
    $(".activity--empty").show();
    $(".mark").show();
  };

  if ($(".activity__list").children() < 1) {
    showEmpty();
  } else {
    hideEmpty();
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hideEmpty = function() {
    $(".activity--empty").hide();
    $(".mark").hide();
  };
  var showEmpty = function() {
    $(".activity--empty").show();
    $(".mark").show();
  };

  function updateNotificationIcon() {
    var notify = $(".indicator");
    var $activity_items = $(".activity__button--user[data-status]"),
      all_read = true;

    // Loop through each .activity__item
    $activity_items.each(function() {
      // If item does NOT have the "read" class, set all_read to false
      if (!$(this).hasClass("activity__button--read")) {
        all_read = false;
      }
    });

    if (all_read) {
      notify.addClass("scale-in");
      $(".mark").attr("data-status", "read");
      $(".mark").html("Mark all unread");
    } else {
      notify.removeClass("scale-in");
      $(".mark").attr("data-status", "unread");
      $(".mark").html("Mark all read");
    }
  }

  var open = "";
  var close = "";
  var bigActive = function() {
    $(".activity__button--user[data-status]")
      .off()
      .on("click", function() {
        var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
        if (status == "unread") {
          $(this)
            .attr("data-status", "read")
            .empty()
            .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + open + " </div>")
            .addClass("activity__button--read");
          $(this)
            .closest(".activity__item--news")
            .addClass("activity__item--read");
        } else {
          $(this)
            .attr("data-status", "unread")
            .empty()
            .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + close + " </div>")
            .removeClass("activity__button--read");
          $(this)
            .closest(".activity__item--news")
            .removeClass("activity__item--read");
        }
        updateNotificationIcon();
      });
    $(".mark")
      .off()
      .on("click", function() {
        var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
        if (!status || status == "unread") {
          $(this).html("Mark all unread").attr("data-status", "read");
          $(".activity__button--user[data-status]").each(function() {
            $(this)
              .attr("data-status", "read")
              .empty()
              .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + open + " </div>")
              .addClass("activity__button--read");
            $(this)
              .closest(".activity__item--news")
              .addClass("activity__item--read");
          });
        } else {
          $(this).html("Mark all read").attr("data-status", "unread");
          $(".activity__button--user[data-status]").each(function() {
            $(this)
              .attr("data-status", "unread")
              .empty()
              .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + close + " </div>")
              .removeClass("activity__button--read");
            $(this)
              .closest(".activity__item--news")
              .removeClass("activity__item--read");
          });
        }
        updateNotificationIcon();
      });
  };
  $(".remove__icon").on("click", function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".activity__item");
    var button = $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .find(".activity__button[data-status]");
    button.addClass("activity__button--read");
    item.addClass("activity__item--read");
    button.attr("data-status", "read");
    item.hide(400, function() {
      item.remove();
    });
    updateNotificationIcon();
  });
  if ($(".activity__list").children() < 1) {
    showEmpty();
  } else {
    hideEmpty();
  }
  var toggleActive = function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  };
  $(".activity__button--user").click(bigActive);
  $(".activity__item--news").each(function(i, e) {
    var button = $(this).find(".activity__button--user");
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 2 + 2)) + 1;
    if ((i + 1) % ranNum == 0) {
      bigActive.call(button);
      $(this).find(".activity__button--user").click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.remove__icon,
.mail__icon {
  font-family: 'Font awesome 5 pro solid 900', sans-serif;
}

.activity__button.activity__button--user.w-embed.activity__button--read {
  color: silver;
}

.activity__button--read .mail__icon {
  font-family: 'Font awesome 5 pro 400', sans-serif;
}

.remove__icon {
  padding: 36px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.activity--empty {
  padding: 36px;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.active {
  background: green
}

.activity__header {
  display: flex;
}

.activity__item {
  font-family: 'Font awesome 5 pro solid 900', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.activity__button--user {
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.activity__button--user>div {
  color: #f8971d;
}

.activity__button--user.activity__button--read>div {
  color: #47a877;
}

.activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}

button {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.indicator {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #cb6f74;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.indicator.scale-in {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-IIED/eyOkM6ihtOiQsX2zizxFBphgnv1zbe1bKA+njdFzkr6cDNy16jfIKWu4FNH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <div class="activity__header">
    <button class="mark">Mark as Read</button>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__list">
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity--empty">All caught up!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: DOM detection is expensive and not usually a good approach. Check status as a callback to whatever delete function removes the items.

Comment: Or are you simply asking how to check for elements? In that case, the answer-as-comment above should do.

Comment: `$(".activity__list").children().length` This code will work for removed/added items but if you hide/show items its another thing

Comment: I would like a working snippet to see how it would work my my code. I tried Yousefs change but it didn't show / hide the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is : `.hide(400` it take 400ms to remove the item but your if condition doesn't wait this time so it works but it didn't count the removed item

To avoid that.. Use the if condition inside the `hide(400 , function(){ remove , if condition})` or Change 400 to 0 it should work too

In the next code I define a function at first called `ToggleShowHideEmpty` then I run it in `hide` callback

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hideEmpty = function() {
    $(".activity--empty").hide();
    $(".mark").hide();
  };
  var showEmpty = function() {
    $(".activity--empty").show();
    $(".mark").show();
  };
  var ToggleShowHideEmpty = function(){    //<<<<<<<<<< Here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if ($(".activity__list .activity__item").length < 1) {
      showEmpty();
    } else {
      hideEmpty();
    }
  };
  function updateNotificationIcon() {
    var notify = $(".indicator");
    var $activity_items = $(".activity__button--user[data-status]"),
      all_read = true;

    // Loop through each .activity__item
    $activity_items.each(function() {
      // If item does NOT have the "read" class, set all_read to false
      if (!$(this).hasClass("activity__button--read")) {
        all_read = false;
      }
    });

    if (all_read) {
      notify.addClass("scale-in");
      $(".mark").attr("data-status", "read");
      $(".mark").html("Mark all unread");
    } else {
      notify.removeClass("scale-in");
      $(".mark").attr("data-status", "unread");
      $(".mark").html("Mark all read");
    }
  }

  var open = "";
  var close = "";
  var bigActive = function() {
    $(".activity__button--user[data-status]")
      .off()
      .on("click", function() {
        var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
        if (status == "unread") {
          $(this)
            .attr("data-status", "read")
            .empty()
            .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + open + " </div>")
            .addClass("activity__button--read");
          $(this)
            .closest(".activity__item--news")
            .addClass("activity__item--read");
        } else {
          $(this)
            .attr("data-status", "unread")
            .empty()
            .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + close + " </div>")
            .removeClass("activity__button--read");
          $(this)
            .closest(".activity__item--news")
            .removeClass("activity__item--read");
        }
        updateNotificationIcon();
      });
    $(".mark")
      .off()
      .on("click", function() {
        var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
        if (!status || status == "unread") {
          $(this).html("Mark all unread").attr("data-status", "read");
          $(".activity__button--user[data-status]").each(function() {
            $(this)
              .attr("data-status", "read")
              .empty()
              .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + open + " </div>")
              .addClass("activity__button--read");
            $(this)
              .closest(".activity__item--news")
              .addClass("activity__item--read");
          });
        } else {
          $(this).html("Mark all read").attr("data-status", "unread");
          $(".activity__button--user[data-status]").each(function() {
            $(this)
              .attr("data-status", "unread")
              .empty()
              .html('<div class="mail__icon"> ' + close + " </div>")
              .removeClass("activity__button--read");
            $(this)
              .closest(".activity__item--news")
              .removeClass("activity__item--read");
          });
        }
        updateNotificationIcon();
      });
  };
  $(".remove__icon").on("click", function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".activity__item");
    var button = $(this)
      .closest(".activity__item")
      .find(".activity__button[data-status]");
    button.addClass("activity__button--read");
    item.addClass("activity__item--read");
    button.attr("data-status", "read");
    item.hide(400, function() {
      item.remove();
      ToggleShowHideEmpty();     //<<<<<<<<<< Here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    });
    updateNotificationIcon();
  });
  var toggleActive = function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  };
  $(".activity__button--user").click(bigActive);
  $(".activity__item--news").each(function(i, e) {
    var button = $(this).find(".activity__button--user");
    ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 2 + 2)) + 1;
    if ((i + 1) % ranNum == 0) {
      bigActive.call(button);
      $(this).find(".activity__button--user").click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.remove__icon,
.mail__icon {
  font-family: 'Font awesome 5 pro solid 900', sans-serif;
}

.activity__button.activity__button--user.w-embed.activity__button--read {
  color: silver;
}

.activity__button--read .mail__icon {
  font-family: 'Font awesome 5 pro 400', sans-serif;
}

.remove__icon {
  padding: 36px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.activity--empty {
  padding: 36px;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.active {
  background: green
}

.activity__header {
  display: flex;
}

.activity__item {
  font-family: 'Font awesome 5 pro solid 900', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.activity__button--user {
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.activity__button--user>div {
  color: #f8971d;
}

.activity__button--user.activity__button--read>div {
  color: #47a877;
}

.activity__item--read {
  background: #fafafa !important;
}

button {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.indicator {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #cb6f74;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.indicator.scale-in {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-IIED/eyOkM6ihtOiQsX2zizxFBphgnv1zbe1bKA+njdFzkr6cDNy16jfIKWu4FNH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <div class="activity__header">
    <button class="mark">Mark as Read</button>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity__list">
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="activity__item activity__item--news">
      <div class="activity__button activity__button--user" data-status="unread">
        <div class="mail__icon"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="remove__icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity--empty">All caught up!</div>
</div>
```